# Azure AD B2C - Unable to sign in existing live.com users in custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, microsoft-account

My company is transitioning from Azure AD B2C user flows to custom policies to accommodate more complex scenarios, such as account linkage. In our directory, we have users with Microsoft accounts (e.g., live.com). We've encountered an issue while attempting to sign in existing users with live.com identities through custom policies.

The problem arises because the "IssuerAssignedId" does not directly map from the "oid" claim, which prevents us from correlating the user with the "IssuerAssignedId" stored in the directory.

What claim should I utilize to correlate the user with the "IssuerAssignedId" stored in the directory within custom policies?

We have tried mapping the "IssuerAssignedId" from "oid"-claims as stated in this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Thank you for any insights or guidance on this matter.

Comment: Have you checked the value of the "sub" claim? Not sure if it is what they use in user flows, but it is a high chance if it is not oid.

Comment: I tried and it worker perfectly! You really saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment an answer. It seems it uses the "sub" claim instead of "oid". "sub" is the standard OpenID Connect claim to identify the user so it makes sense.